# How to execute one command over the files where the paths of all the files are listed in the file?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a text file (`file.txt`) in which I the paths of all the files on which the commands have to be executed.  How to iterate over a `for` loop and execute the commands on the file in each path of the text file?  I have tried this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
LOC=pathto the file

for f in $LOC;
do
        sed -i '1i\10004' $f;

done
```

Comment: Related: [Pass arguments from file line by line to function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020947/pass-arguments-from-file-line-by-line-to-function)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shell loop, because **even with `-i`, the `sed` command accepts multiple filename arguments and operates on each named file separately**. Unless all the files are already fully backed up, though, I encourage you to use `-i.bak`--with whatever suffix you prefer, it doesn't have to be `.bak`. Using `sed -i` without making a backup file often results in accidental data loss. (This recommendation would apply equally if you were running `sed` once for each file in a loop.)

Since `sed` accepts multiple filename arguments, and since you can use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xargs.1.html) instead of a loop to build up the list of filenames and pass them to `sed`, you can do everything in one short command. Depending on your needs, you could just run that command instead of writing a script. Or your script might consist just of that one command, aside from the `#!/bin/sh` hashbang at the top. You do not need to use any shell variables, nor any loops or other control structures in the shell. (Processing text, such as a list of filenames, using a loop in a shell script, is [often not the best approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).)

I assume the input file contains one filename per line, even though separating filenames with null characters rather than newlines would be better (in that it would work correctly even if some filenames contained newline characters). Assuming that's the case, here's a command you can use:

```bash
xargs -d'\n' -a files sed -i.bak '1i\10004'
```

- `-d'\n'` tells `xargs` that the filenames it reads are separated by newlines, that is, that they appear one per line in the input file.
- `-a files` tells `xargs` to read its input from a file named *`files`*. (You could use redirection and write `<files` instead of `-a files`, as is often done.) Replace *`files`* with the actual filename of the file you wish to read the filenames from.
- `-i.bak` performs in-place modifications (`-i`), as you know. The inclusion of `.bak`, with no space, in that same command-line argument, tells `sed` to save backup files with a *`.bak`* suffix. If you want a different suffix, use that instead of *`.bak`*. If you *really* want to do this without creating backup files, then you can simply omit the suffix and write just `-i`.
- As you know, `'1i\10004'` passes `1i\10004` to `sed` to use as its command for processing lines of the file. (Other readers will wish to replace this with whatever `sed` command they are using.)

Comment: Thank you,I got  xargs argument list too long error after executing it.can any one tell me how to overcome it.